# upload the file in the server or iis

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

How do I save a file in IIS using ASP.NET

I want to save my file in this path:

```
Server.MapPath("http://192.168.1.6:150/clinicalclient/Rosefiles/" 
                 + DropDownList1.Text + '/');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there, I think you want:

```
Server.MapPath("~/clinicalclient/Rosefiles/" + DropDownList1.Text);
```